# Simple example for ImpredicativeTypes

Tags: haskell, impredicativetypes

The GHC user's guide describes the [impredicative polymorphism extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#impredicative-polymorphism) with reference to the following example:

```
f :: Maybe (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Maybe ([Int], [Char])
f (Just g) = Just (g [3], g "hello")
f Nothing  = Nothing
```

However, when I define this example in a file and try to call it, I get a type error:

```
ghci> f (Just reverse)

<interactive>:8:9:
    Couldn't match expected type `forall a. [a] -> [a]'
                with actual type `[a0] -> [a0]'
    In the first argument of `Just', namely `reverse'
    In the first argument of `f', namely `(Just reverse)'
    In the expression: f (Just reverse)
ghci> f (Just id)

<interactive>:9:9:
    Couldn't match expected type `forall a. [a] -> [a]'
                with actual type `a0 -> a0'
    In the first argument of `Just', namely `id'
    In the first argument of `f', namely `(Just id)'
    In the expression: f (Just id)
```

Seemingly only `undefined`, `Nothing`, or `Just undefined` satisfies the type-checker.

I have two questions, therefore:

- Can the above function be called with `Just f` for any non-bottom `f`?
- Can someone provide an example of a value only definable with impredicative polymorphism, and usable in a non-trivial way?

The latter is particularly with the [HaskellWiki page on Impredicative Polymorphism](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Impredicative_types) in mind, which currently makes a decidedly unconvincing case for the existence of the extension.

Comment: Interesting. It's acceptable to say `forall a. [a] -> [a]`. `forall a. Maybe ([a] -> [a])` fails, because the type checker seems to try to instantiate `a` to both `Int` and `Char`. `Maybe (forall a. [a] -> [a])` fails, because it expects `forall a. [a] -> [a]`, but it gets a `[a0] -> [a0]` where `a0` is fresh. So, *with* `Maybe`, the nested type scheme is only instantiated once, but *without* `Maybe`, everything is just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of how one project, [const-math-ghc-plugin](https://github.com/kfish/const-math-ghc-plugin), uses `ImpredicativeTypes` to specify a list of matching rules.

The idea is that when we have an expression of the form `App (PrimOp nameStr) (Lit litVal)`, we want to look up the appropriate rule based upon the primop name.  A `litVal` will be either a `MachFloat d` or `MachDouble d` (`d` is a `Rational`).  If we find a rule, we want to apply the function for that rule to `d` converted to the correct type.

The function `mkUnaryCollapseIEEE` does this for unary functions.

```
mkUnaryCollapseIEEE :: (forall a. RealFloat a => (a -> a))
                    -> Opts
                    -> CoreExpr
                    -> CoreM CoreExpr
mkUnaryCollapseIEEE fnE opts expr@(App f1 (App f2 (Lit lit)))
    | isDHash f2, MachDouble d <- lit = e d mkDoubleLitDouble
    | isFHash f2, MachFloat d  <- lit = e d mkFloatLitFloat
    where
        e d = evalUnaryIEEE opts fnE f1 f2 d expr
```

The first argument needs to have a Rank-2 type, because it will be instantiated at either `Float` or `Double` depending on the literal constructor.  The list of rules looks like this:

```
unarySubIEEE :: String -> (forall a. RealFloat a => a -> a) -> CMSub
unarySubIEEE nm fn = CMSub nm (mkUnaryCollapseIEEE fn)

subs =
    [ unarySubIEEE "GHC.Float.exp"    exp
    , unarySubIEEE "GHC.Float.log"    log
    , unarySubIEEE "GHC.Float.sqrt"   sqrt
    -- lines omitted
    , unarySubIEEE "GHC.Float.atanh"  atanh
    ]
```

This is ok, if a bit too much boilerplate for my taste.

However, there's a similar function `mkUnaryCollapsePrimIEEE`.  In this case, the rules are different for different GHC versions.  If we want to support multiple GHCs, it gets a bit tricky.  If we took the same approach, the `subs` definition would require a lot of CPP, which can be unmaintainable.  Instead, we defined the rules in a separate file for each GHC version.  However, `mkUnaryCollapsePrimIEEE` isn't available in those modules due to circular import issues.  We could probably re-structure the modules to make it work, but instead we defined the rulesets as:

```
unaryPrimRules :: [(String, (forall a. RealFloat a => a -> a))]
unaryPrimRules =
    [ ("GHC.Prim.expDouble#"    , exp)
    , ("GHC.Prim.logDouble#"    , log)
    -- lines omitted
    , ("GHC.Prim.expFloat#"     , exp)
    , ("GHC.Prim.logFloat#"     , log)
    ]
```

By using `ImpredicativeTypes`, we can keep a list of Rank-2 functions, ready to use for the first argument to `mkUnaryCollapsePrimIEEE`.  The alternatives would be much more CPP/boilerplate, changing the module structure (or circular imports), or a lot of code duplication.  None of which I would like.

I do seem to recall GHC HQ indicating that they would like to drop support for the extension, but perhaps they've reconsidered.  It is quite useful at times.

Comment: Now both halves of my question are answered, but unfortunately not both in the same answer :) I'm accepting this one anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Isn't it just that `ImpredicativeTypes` has been quietly dropped with the new typechecker in ghc-7+ ? Note that ideone.com still uses ghc-6.8 and indeed your program use to run fine :

```
{-# OPTIONS -fglasgow-exts  #-}

f :: Maybe (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Maybe ([Int], [Char])
f (Just g) = Just (g [3], g "hello")
f Nothing  = Nothing

main   = print $ f (Just reverse)
```

prints `Just ([3],"olleh")` as expected; see http://ideone.com/KMASZy

`augustss` gives a handsome use case -- some sort of imitation Python dsl -- and a defense of the extension here: http://augustss.blogspot.com/2011/07/impredicative-polymorphism-use-case-in.html referred to in the ticket here http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4295

Comment: `f` requires `ImpredicativeTypes` to compile (if I give only `RankNTypes`, GHC even suggests the extension), so it certainly hasn't been *completely* dropped.

Comment: Yes, it immediately requires you to use the extension if you attempt the syntax `Maybe   (forall a . [a] -> [a])`, as it used to do; but then it ignores the plain meaning of the signature, except in some vestigial cases.

Comment: I have some code that uses `ImpredicativeTypes` to achieve `rules ::  [(String, (forall a. RealFloat a => a -> a))]`, which works fine with ghc-7.6.  The alternatives appear much less attractive.

Comment: @JohnL: that would actually answer my second question if you want to post a quick summary.

Comment: Doesn't Lennart A's discussion answer your second question? A revision of your function following John L's works fine `g :: [(Int, forall a. [a] -> [a])] -> Maybe ([Int], [Char]); g []  = Nothing ; g ((n,ff):nfs) = Just (ff [3], ff "hello")`  My thought was that you don't want to depend on it working in ghc-7.8

Answer (score 5):

Note this workaround:

```
justForF :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Maybe (forall a. [a] -> [a])
justForF = Just

ghci> f (justForF reverse)
Just ([3],"olleh")
```

Or this one (which is basically the same thing inlined):

```
ghci> f $ (Just :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Maybe (forall a. [a] -> [a])) reverse
Just ([3],"olleh")
```

Seems like the type inference has problems infering the type of the `Just` in your case and we have to tell it the type.

I have no clue if it's a bug or if there is a good reason for it.. :)

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting! I had already tried annotating `reverse` but in retrospect that wasn't going to work. I won't accept this answer yet, though, because this solution is, uh, kind of icky :P

Comment: Impredicative polymorphism does not play nice with HM style typing.  Universal types are in a sense "opened" automatically in Haskell and similar languages. That is, type variables are quantified at the outermost level.